# Key for remove doubles

Tags: shortcut

Every time I remove doubles, I go space bar, remove doubles, and press enter. What is the "legit" way of doing this? Is there a faster short cut key? If not its fine.

Comment: Hello :). Since 2.8 it's ALT+M and *by Distance*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2.8 it's named Merge by Distance.

*Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by Distance*
Shortcut: <kbd>Alt + M</kbd> > *By Distance*

[image]